# Downloading Ubuntu to OS X, installing on a laptop with no OS

Tags: boot, usb, macosx

As it says in the title, I want to install Ubuntu on a Windows laptop with no OS. I'd prefer to use a USB boot rather than a DVD. How can I create an appropriate USB boot stick from OS X?

Comment: what has mac os x to do with this question?

Comment: Are you downloading the iso to OSX? Try this installation instructions http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx .However it is a little bit hard. You should try to make the live usb in a friend's computer running Windows or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

To create a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu on OS X follow these instructions:

1. [Download Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
2. Open the Terminal (in /Applications/Utilities/ or query Terminal in Spotlight).
3. Convert the `.iso` file to `.img` using the convert option of hdiutil (e.g.,`hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img ~/path/to/ubuntu.iso`). Note: OS X tends to put the `.dmg` ending on the output file automatically.
4. Run diskutil list to get the current list of devices.
5. Insert your USB stick.
6. Run diskutil list again and determine the device node assigned to your flash media (e.g. `/dev/disk2`).
7. Run `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN` (replace N with the disk number from the last command; in the previous example, N would be 2).
8. Execute `sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m` (replace `/path/to/downloaded.img` with the path where the image file is located; for example, `./ubuntu.imgor` `./ubuntu.dmg`).
9. Run `diskutil eject /dev/diskN` and remove your flash media when the command completes.

After you complete all of these, just insert your USB stick in the the laptop with no OS and start the laptop. If your laptop does not automatically boot from the USB stick, you might need to change (usually from BIOS) the device from which the laptop starts up to the USB.

Sources:

- http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx
- http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

Comment: I followed these instructions and successfully copied everything on the img to the USB disk using dd but after that, the OS says that the drive is in an unreadable format and needs to be initiated. I've tried this 3 time with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bootable USB stick from any OS and it should work on any system. This means that if you create an USB bootable disk from Mac it will also work on any Windows PC (and not just on other macs).

To create a bootable USB system you should follow the very good guide you can find here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

What the guide misses is that you need to double check what partition the USB has been formatted with. If you formatted the USB with some OSX specific partition table it might not work as a bootable drive.

So the first thing to do is to open Disk Utility. Select the USB drive from the list on the left and click on the "Partition" tab.

From there select:

- Volume Scheme: 1 Partition
- Click the Options button, from the dialog select "Master Boot Record" option and press OK
- Format: MS-DOS (FAT)

Click on apply and then follow the aforementioned guide.